# cocos compile -p android doesn't work on version 3.7

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am not able to compile using cocos console.

Running command: compile
Building mode: debug
Using Eclipse project : /Users/werplay/Documents/Cocos2d Projects/XYZZZ/proj.android
Android platform not specified, searching a default one...
running: '/Applications/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/android update project -t android-10 -p /Users/werplay/Documents/Cocos2d Projects/XYZZZ/proj.android'

Error: Argument 'Projects/XYZZZ/proj.android' is not recognized.

```
   Usage:
   android [global options] update project [action options]
   Global options:
```

-h --help       : Help on a specific command.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.

```
                     Action "update project":
```

Updates an Android project (must already have an AndroidManifest.xml).
Options:
  -l --library    : Directory of an Android library to add, relative to this
                    project's directory.
  -p --path       : The project's directory. [required]
  -n --name       : Project name.
  -t --target     : Target ID to set for the project.
  -s --subprojects: Also updates any projects in sub-folders, such as test
                    projects.
Error running command, return code: 1.

HELP :(

Answer (score 0):

change the path "/Users/werplay/Documents/Cocos2d Projects/XYZZZ/" to "/Users/werplay/Documents/Cocos2d_Projects/XYZZZ/"